VSCodeを使ってJavaのプログラミング問題を解こうとすると、最後の一文の入力がされないまま処理が始まる。
プログラミング問題の入力をコピーし、F5などでデバッグモードで起動し、VSCodeのターミナルに右クリックして入力すると必ず起きます。
scannerのnextInt()を別の物に変更しても、そもそも情報の取得が途中で止まっていて関係ありませんでした。
余分な文字受け入れを行うという方法をやってみても、勝手に処理が始まり何もできないままでした。
4 2
6 6 6
4 6 4
6 1 1
4 4 4

この入力が
4 2
6 6 6
4 6 4
6 1 1

入力は改行も一緒に入っています。
今現在はVSCodeでしか動作を確認していません。
使っている拡張機能は以下です。
どれを載せるべきか分からないので、Javaを使う上でインストールしたものを載せます。

Debugger for Java :ver0.58.0
Extension Pack for Java : v0.29.0
Gradle for Java : v3.16.4
Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat : v1.33.0
Maven for Java : v0.44.0
Project Manager for Java : v0.24.0
Test Runner for Java : v0.42.0

このように最後の一文を飛ばして入力されてしまいます。
以下は記述したコードです。
コードに誤りがありましたので修正いたしました。
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int boxCount = scanner.nextInt();

    int ballRadius = scanner.nextInt();
    ballRadius *= 2;

    int[] passingBoxArray = new int[boxCount];
    Arrays.fill(passingBoxArray, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {

        int heigth = scanner.nextInt();
        int width = scanner.nextInt();
        int depth = scanner.nextInt();

        if (heigth < ballRadius) {
            continue;
        }
        if (width < ballRadius) {
            continue;
        }
        if (depth < ballRadius) {
            continue;
        }
        passingBoxArray[i] = i + 1;
    }
    scanner.close();
    for (int i : passingBoxArray) {
        if (i == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}


VSCode以外の環境で試していますか？ 試しているならそれはどういう環境なのか、その時の動作はどうなってるのか等の詳細を質問を編集して追記してみてください。VSCodeでしか試していないなら、プログラムの問題も考えられますので、cubickさんコメントのようにソースコードを提示してみてください。その他使っているOSやJDKとかの情報・版数などもあると良いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してみてください。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

質問の状況は正確に記述されていますか？ 提示されたソースコードと実行しているプログラムが実は対応していないと言った状況が発生していませんか？
Online Java compiler | ブラウザでプログラミング・実行が ...
上記のサイトで質問に提示されたソースコードとデータ(画面左下の緑色の実行(Ctrl+Enter)ボタンの下に「入力」欄があります)を入力して実行したところでは、以下のようなエラーが発生しています。
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:941)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)

提示されたソースコードをどのように入力したかによってエラーメッセージの該当行は変わりますが、ここではint heigth = scanner.nextInt();の行でエラーが発生していることを示しています。
上記エラーが何故発生しているかというと、for (int i = 0; i <= boxCount; i++) {ループの継続判定条件i <= boxCountが間違っていて、iは0から始まっているのにi <= boxCountまでループを継続してしまうので、指定の回数よりも1回多く廻ってしまい、データが無いのでエラーになっています。
この状況は、質問である「最後の一文の入力がされないまま処理が始まる。」とは違ったものであるため、提示されたソースコードが問題発生しているものと違う可能性があります。
質問に提示されたソースコードで言えば、for (int i = 0; i <= boxCount; i++) {の行のi <= boxCountをi < boxCountとして=を削除すれば、エラーは発生せず終了するようになります。
質問内容と問題が発生している対象実行プログラムの差などを確認してみてください。

記事更新後の追記
私の上記助言により更新されたソースコードですが、上記に紹介したオンライン環境ではエラーが発生せず終了します。
実行後の出力ウインドウには以下の結果が表示されます。
1
2

上記はpassingBoxArrayの中身が以下になっていて、3番目(インデックス[2])の値が -1 であるため表示せずにループ終了するためですね。
[0] = 1
[1] = 2
[2] = -1
[3] = 4


注) なお質問のソースコードが修正されてしまい回答と合わなくなっていますが、元は以下であり、配列の値を順番にチェックしていって、-1 ならそこで表示せずに「ループを終了する」形でした。
    for (int i : passingBoxArray) {
        if (i == -1) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }


ということでソースコード的には問題無さそうなので、残るはツールとかの組み合わせ・構成・版数などの関係でしょうか？
あるいは実は操作ミスか動作の理解不足とか？「最後の一文の入力がされないまま処理が始まる。」ということですが、プログラムは既に動いているので処理は始まっているはずなので、どのような段階まで動かした状態からどのように変化してしまうからおかしいといった詳細も一つ一つ手順を追って記述した方が良いでしょう。
私自身は上記助言記事でわかるようにJavaの環境を持っておらずVSCodeも使っていないのでこれ以上は出来ませんが、どなたか既に類似の環境を持っていたら検証してもらえるかもしれないので、パソコンやOSの種類・版数とか、VSCodeや入れているツール類の設定・構成情報を追記してみてください。
あるいは誰かの助言・回答を待って時間を費やすよりは、環境をいったん全部クリアして再インストールしてみるのも手かもしれません。

ご指摘の中で、最後の処理の[break]が正しくは[continue]にしないと、値が-1ではないものを表示するという処理に成っていないことを修正しました。すると、VSCodeの入力が最後まで受け付けられ、正しい出力になりました。
ブレークポイントをscanner.close()する前に置いておくと今回の問題が起こるようでしたので今後はscannerの位置に注意していきます。
丁寧なご指摘誠にありがとうございました。ご指摘の反映が遅れて申し訳ありません。
